# Protractor Angular 2 e2e testing: Find element and perform action after login

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

I just new into e2e testing with protractor in angular 2. I'm having problems finding an element after login and perform an action on it (click).

After login it builds the page with message-components which are in a parent message-component. When running the test looking for the parent component it succeeds, running the second test finding the child component and perform an action it succeeds as wel. But when removing the first test it fails. I am testing on component level and I only want to test the necessary. The first test shouldn't be necessary here. See code:

```
declare var by: any;
declare var browser: any;
declare var element: any;

function login() {

    let usernameInput = element(by.css("input[name=\"username\"]"));
    let passwordInput = element(by.css("input[name=\"password\"]"));
    let submit = element(by.css("button[type=\"submit\"]"));

    usernameInput.sendKeys("Username");
    passwordInput.sendKeys("welcome");

    submit.click();
}

describe("my-App", function () {
    let page: WebPage;

    beforeEach(() => {
        page = new WebPage();
    });

    // If I remove this it doesnt work
    it("If we provide credentials to the login form we should be authenticated and login", () => {
        page.navigateTo();
        login();
        expect(element(by.css("parent-element")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
    });

    it("should open conversation-component when clicking on a message", () => {
        page.navigateTo();
        // Do login here when the first it() is removed.
        // login();

        element(by.css("parent-element")).isPresent().then(function () {
            let message = element.all(by.css(".child-message")).first()
            message.click();
        });

        /* 
        == not working either ==
        browser.wait(element(by.css("parent-component")).isPresent(), 5000).then(function () {
            element.all(by.css(".child-message")).first().click();
        }); 
        */

    })

    expect(element(by.css("conversation-component")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
});
```

Don't really understand the control flow. Retrieving messages takes a few seconds. I played around with the timeout in the config but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You should login with a `beforeAll` statement this will run before all of the code in the describe block only once.

```
beforeAll(() => {
    page.navigateTo();
    login();
});
```

Additionally you can move your page = new WebPage(); outside of the beforeEach(()=>{}) block.

```
describe("my-App", function () {

    let page: WebPage;
    page = new WebPage();

    beforeAll(() => {
        page.navigateTo();
        login();
    });
```

#### Answer to your second question about waiting

Your test is trying to interact with elements before the page is fully loaded. It is pretty common for this to occur in an app that is not purely Angular.js.

Try this code (I am not 100% sure it will work since it appears you are using typescript).

```
it('should open conversation-component when clicking on a message',() => {
    page.navigateTo();
    //browser.sleep(10000); //Uncomment this if the below solution does not work.
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    let message = $$('.child-message').first();
    var isClickable = EC.elementToBeClickable(message);
    browser.wait(isClickable,10000);
    message.click();
});
```

The isPresent() function can be used (in very creative ways) to wait for elements but the ExpectedConditions are much more suited for this. Please see  this link to learn more about them. http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The thing is that it can't find the message (child). It seems after login it directly looks for the message and it is not rendered yet.

Comment: I updated the answer to try to address finding the message element.